# Почему не работает запрос к БД?

Tags: php, pdo

Из формы получаю запрос

```
<input type="search" name="q">
```

В модели, которая наследуется от абстрактного класса:

```
public static function search(array $searchData){
      if (empty($searchData['q'])) {
          throw new InvalidArgumentException('Запрос');
        }
    }
```

Контроллер

```
public function search(){
      try{
          $serch = Article::search($_GET);
      }catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
          $this->view->renderHtml('search/search.php', ['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
          return;
    }
    $searchq = $_GET['q'];
    $articles = Article::searchArticles($searchq);
    $this->view->renderHtml('search/search.php', ['articles' => $articles]
  );
  }
```

Т.е. я в переменную $searchq записываю get запрос.

Если что-то найдется будет выведено через foreach

Абстрактный класс, который наследует модель:

```
public static function searchArticles(string $searchq): array{
        $db = Db::getInstance();
        return $db->query('SELECT * FROM `' . static::getTableName() . '` WHERE `name` LIKE \'%searchq=:searchq%\' LIMIT 1', [':searchq' => $searchq], static::class);
    }
```

Я по идеи передаю данные в функцию, которая в свою очередь должна передать их в запрос.

Но проблема в том, что этого не происходит.

Подскажите пожалуйста почему и как это исправить?

Comment: `Я по идеи передаю` - так проверьте это. Хотя бы `var_dump` воткните и посмотрите был ли вызван, что в нём оказалось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда передаёте в запрос параметр в `LIKE` условие, надо писать вот так:

```
WHERE `name` LIKE :searchq
```

А в параметры уже передавать что-то такое

```
'%' . strtr($searchq , ['%' => '\\%', '_' => '\\_', '\\' => '\\\\']) . '%'
```

Дело в том, что PDO сам оборачивает параметры в `'` кавычки, если это нужно (вернее, если указать, что тип параметра - строка, а он такой по умолчанию).

Плюс, PDO не вставляет параметры в часть выражения, то есть следующие конструкции работать не будут:

```
VALUES (:values)

LIKE 'проверка строки :stringPart'

a = b + 12:endOfNum
```

Подробнее о тонкостях работы с PDO вы можете прочитать в [документации](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php)

Comment: спасибо большущие!